# How to close running CMD in background when using Threading?

Tags: python, tkinter

**Code**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import threading

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    # Gets the requested values of the height and width.
    window_width = root.winfo_reqwidth()
    window_height = root.winfo_reqheight()
    # Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
    position_right = int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - window_width/2)
    position_down = int(root.winfo_screenheight()/2 - window_height/2)
    # Positions the window in the center of the page.
    root.geometry(f"+{position_right}+{position_down}")
    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Sign off check")
        self.master.geometry('800x350')
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        def refresh_progress():
            threading.Timer(5.0, refresh_progress).start()

        refresh_progress()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output**

Running via CMD - Simple blank Tkinter window is opened up and function (`def refresh_progress():`) is running every 5 seconds.

**Problem**

My problem is - Soon as I close the Tkinter window (by pressing 'x' top right corner). The CMD window is still running in background.

**Question**

How can I end the CMD from running in background - as soon as the Tkinter window is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use my full code here

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import threading

def on_closing():
    # you can add a various command here, for example like messagebox or something
    timer.cancel()
    root.destroy()
    sys.exit()

def main():
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing) # when user click "X"
    # Gets the requested values of the height and width.
    window_width = root.winfo_reqwidth()
    window_height = root.winfo_reqheight()
    # Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
    position_right = int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - window_width/2)
    position_down = int(root.winfo_screenheight()/2 - window_height/2)
    # Positions the window in the center of the page.
    root.geometry(f"+{position_right}+{position_down}")
    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Sign off check")
        self.master.geometry('800x350')
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        def refresh_progress():
            global timer
            timer = threading.Timer(5.0, refresh_progress)
            timer.start()

        refresh_progress()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Solved by adding the protocol "WM_DELETE_WINDOW" to `root`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! This freezes the application every time I try it.

Comment: oh yeah, i forgot to add root.destroy

Comment: let's try again

Comment: Root is not defined

Comment: try again ok, i fixed that `root`

Comment: Nope, closed the application - but the cmd is still running

Comment: yeah, let me fix it again

Comment: ok, i fixed it, let's check it out (I tried too and it worked for me)